# sql mode only full group by

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` . This problem will be come some windows computer but some other computer and server i didn't get any related problem.

So i get the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` error from the following code:

```
$yearMonthTotalyUsers = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

$YearMonthyTotalyUser = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered))+1, count(*) 
FROM dot_users
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
group by MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered))
") or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($YearMonthyTotalyUser, MYSQLI_NUM)) {  
    $yearMonthTotalyUsers[$row[0]] = $row[1];  
}
```

anyone can help me why i am getting this problem and how to fix it?

Here is the full Error Message:

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'data.dot_users.user_registered' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: @ErayBalkanli I have added full error message in the question.

Comment: I am really surprised that full group by mode does not support expressions on the `group by` keys.

Comment: "I am really surprised that full group by mode does not support expressions on the group by keys. " Yes me too @GordonLinoff because i could not reprodure it.. MySQL seams to support expressions with sql mode only full group by https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohFmo6ThCbYVJADfp1kNdi/0 from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 8 just fine  .. looks like the topicstarter MySQL version is bugged or something like that..

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL version seams "bugged" that it requires the SELECT column name/alias/expression to be the same as the GROUP BY with sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY 
You can try to wrap it in a delivered table /subquery approach.

```
SELECT 
   user_registered_month + 1
 , `count`
FROM (

SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered)) AS user_registered_month, count(*) AS `count`
FROM dot_users
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
group by MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered))

) AS alias
```

Or if the database supports it this is also possible, MySQL for example supports this kind of reusing of aliases

```
SELECT 
   user_registered_month + 1
 , `count`
FROM (

SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered)) AS user_registered_month, count(*) AS `count`
FROM dot_users
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_registered)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
group by user_registered_month
ORDER BY user_registered_month

) AS alias
```